# Como usar clipboard de Android en scripts Python

Tags: android, python, python-3.x

Estoy realizando unas pruebas para un script para Android. Se trata de una serie de numeros generados de manera aleatoria que automáticamente y sin mostrar nada en pantalla, se van al clipboard y queda a disposición para ser copiad en cualquier sitio.
De momento, hago funcionar sin problema el siguiente fragmento de código en Windows que realiza la función de introducción de datos al clipboard.

```
#Introducción automática del mensaje string a clipboard
import os
def addToClipBoard(text):
    command = 'echo ' + text.strip() + '| clip'
    os.system(command)

addToClipBoard(result2)
```

Sin embargo no soy capaz de saber como realizar esto mismo en Android. He visto que [Androidhelper](https://kylelk.github.io/html-examples/androidhelper.html) tiene una función (setClipboard)

> setClipboard(text) Put text in the clipboard. text (String) Creates a new 
>     AndroidFacade that simplifies the interface to various Android APIs.

Estoy realizando las ejecuciones con QPython3.2.
¿Alguien me puede echar un cablecillo?

---

EDITO:
Lo he solucionado de la siguiente forma:

```
from androidhelper import Android
droid = Android()
#setClipboard
droid.setClipboard("Hello World")
#getClipboard
clipboard = droid.getClipboard().result
```

Comment: por que le añadiste "solved " a tu pregunta?

Comment: DDR2348, No coloques "solucionado", si la respuesta dada ha solucionado tu pregunta, **[acéptala](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** *(o publica tu propia respuesta)*.

Answer (score 0):

QPython no soporta todas las características de Python, especialmente aquellas que requieren de una interacción directa con el SO. Lo que puedes hacer en este caso es usar SL4A mediante el módulo `androidhelper` tal como comentas:

```
import androidhelper

droid = androidhelper.Android()
droid.setClipboard("Hola Python!")
```

`androidhelper`  interactuá con `SL4A` mediante la clase `Android`, la cual tiene `setClipboard` como método de instancia. Solo tienes que crea una instancia de la misma previamente para usarlo por tanto.

> **Nota:** para que funcione correctamente hay que asegurarse de tener activado SL4A:
>
> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]